# row and column layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am making a music player and downloader.
So i have a search and a listview which shows the songs.
When i click on a song the following menu with items opens and then i click on play, download or share text to do action.

İt Works well for me but i want a customized version of this which shows eack item inside box maybe side by side in two rows.
i would then change each item by an icon to look better.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


<item
    android:id="@+id/download"
    android:title="@string/audio_download"
   />
<item
    android:id="@+id/bitrate"
    android:title="@string/audio_bitrate"

     />
<item
    android:id="@+id/play"
    android:title="@string/audio_play"
     />
<item
    android:id="@+id/share"
    android:title="@string/audio_share"
     />
<item
    android:id="@+id/copy"
    android:title="@string/audio_copy"
     />

</menu>
```

Comment: You probably want a GridView. Or a GridLayout, if the items will have different sizes.

Comment: yes... a kind of